# github actions assign diff between branches to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, github-actions

i tried to assign the diff files between master and my branch with the next command

`ALL_FILES=$(git --no-pager diff --name-only $BASE_BRANCH..$PR_BRANCH -- | grep -viF "$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D $BASE_BRANCH..$PR_BRANCH)") | grep -viF "segment-validation.yml")`

but if the second grep dont trow results the command fails
`grep -viF "$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D $BASE_BRANCH..$PR_BRANCH)")`

i tried with || true at final but it results with a null list of files even the first argument returns file names